# I am trying to convert RGB to Lab and then zero the a and b channels to get a grayscale image but I get an image with reddish orange tint

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, python-imaging-library

My code:

```
imgrey = np.asarray(ibuffer).copy()
grey = cv2.cvtColor(imgrey, cv2.COLOR_BGR2Lab)
grey[:,:,1] = 0
grey[:,:,2] = 0
grey = cv2.cvtColor(grey,cv2.COLOR_LAB2BGR)
photo = Image.fromarray(grey)
photo = resize(photo)
photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(photo)
canvas.photo = photo
canvas.create_image(0,0,anchor="nw",image = photo)
```

I want to manipulate my image using its Lab values but doing so gives incorrect output when the manipulated Lab values are converted back to RGB.

[Orginal Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/745cD.jpg)

[Output Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aa08H.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want a grayscale image OpenCV has cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
This will return a one-channel gray image. You could also just use the L channel from the LAB image, it looks like a grayscale image (but I don't think it's exactly the same).

Modifying the 'a' and 'b' channels of a lab image can be a little unintuitive since each one controls a different saturation of color with a 'positive' and 'negative' value. It's a sliding scale that goes in two directions that starts at 128. This is why setting them to zero isn't gray, it's actually full saturation in one direction. I suspect if you set both of them to 128 you'll get what you want.

Comment: Yup setting the 'a' and 'b' channels to 128 did the trick. COLOR_BGR2GRAY returned a bit darker image while latter returned a lighter image. I am working on an editor that finally outputs the file in CMYK mode for printing. So I find it necessary to use a device independent color space to do my color conversions and manipulations.